# Meaning of "if you want to exchange gear for promo"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of this model's response to a photograph?

> Well I have enough work on my plate, but **if you want to exchange gear
>   for promo**, I'm always cool with that!

Comment: response to a request to be photographed I presume you mean?

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that the model already has enough stuff to do for a living, but she would not mind doing more (helping the advertiser promote their clothes by doing another photo shoot) if she got gear (those clothes) in return.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means he/she will, in return for being given some clothes (gear), wear those clothes (promote them) in the other photo-shoots (the enough work they already have) and let it be known what clothes they are.

I don't think it means being paid for doing photo-shoots with clothing, however expensive it may be.

Comment: Hi! What is the difference in meaning between what you said and what I said? =)

Comment: @Jasper Loy The second sentence. You said "she would not mind doing more [photo shoots] if she got clothes in return". I think he/she is saying he/she will not do more but will wear those clothes in his/her existing photo-shoots to promote them. There is a world of difference.

Comment: Hmm, I am still trying to figure this out... =)

Comment: @Jasper Loy You say he/she means they will do more work. I say he/she means they will not.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the model industry but I would bet that not many paid photoshoots allow the model to choose what clothes they wear during the shoot.

Comment: @Jim Hmmm. "bet that not many"... leaves plenty of room for some.

Comment: Yeah, I debated about saying, "very few" or "not many".  In reality I think that ***no*** professional director lets the model choose her own attire for the shoot.  Models are mostly either modeling clothes, in which case it will always be the clothes being advertised, or participating in the creation of a scene, such as advertising for a resort, or advertising a product.  In any event I think the artistic director will know exactly what look they're going for and will have preselected the clothing that best portrays that vision:  "We need her to look like a sophisticated hockey mom" etc.

Comment: I wonder if it means, if you give me the clothes, then I will wear them around town (when I'm not on set).  And when people ask me about what I'm wearing I can tell them.

Comment: Maybe. I think the more famous models can say "I want to wear this" and be all deva about it and get their way though so I think it does happen. What I doubt happens is that models who are already busy agree to do even more work but for clothes instead of money.